# Excel JavaScript Api Custom function with custom type paramter

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I am trying to implement Excel custom function with `Script Lab`.

I tried code below:

```
/**
 * 返回米可爱分享
 * @customfunction
 * @param {MeekouType} input
 */
function meekou(input: MeekouType) {
  return input;
}

export enum MeekouType {
  Phone = "Phone",
  Email = "Email",
}
```

There is no type smart pips for `@param`.

Here is my screenshot.

[image]

I prefer it will have message for enum like below

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this type of worksheet intellisense is currently supported in Office.js

Comment: This feature is not currently supported in Custom Function.